Seamless application sharing on Windows
In VirtualBox, there's seamless mode which allows windows to be interlaced with the host operating system.

(Notice how Internet Explorer is next to the iTunes window)
Is there anything similar but for a server/host machine instead? I have two Windows 11 laptops, and I would like to share windows from one machine to another.
With VNC, we can share the entire screen, but not individual windows.
I have tried the following applications to no avail:

WinSwitch - Seems to be abandoned, the download installer is missing
WinFlector - Doesn't work, when I connect to the host, it either shows black or crashes
Xpra - Only works for Linux hosts. Not when both machines are Windows.
RemoteApp - Outdated guide, though I imagine this should still work?

In short, I want to setup a server that would allow me to choose which applications to share. Then on the client, I can launch applications, which would run on the host, but its display window would be transmitted to the client.
Is there anything like this?

Doubt that. VNC is a like a standard protocol and a user is not even supposed to use a specfic client for a specfic server. For it to work the VNC server would need to be "window-aware" send image of them separately (and the client would need to be aware of that). Anything, if exist, that can fulfill your desire won't really be leveraging the VNC protocol (only). (But apparently you are just "abusing the term VNC.)

Actually yeah that's fair, I'm misusing the term VNC. There's no reason that it must use this protocol.

Your question lists several of these tools already, meaning you're aware of them, but notes that you haven't tried Remote App, which is the built-in Windows method. Your question is asking us to list or recommend products, currently, and THAT sort of question is explicitly off topic on this site. I recommend that you begin looking more into Remote App, or find out some of the others are failing, and then present THAT question, about how to get that product working, because that will be on topic here.
